# How much can I learn using the Microsoft Virtual Academy alone?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I know this is a little vague, but I'm wondering how thorough the MVA is. I'm a novice, I have a job separate from anything to do with computers, but I'd like to become as proficient as possible in, say, Visual Studio (i.e., writing programs, maybe phone apps, etc.), so before I start watching all the videos and taking their little quizzes, I'd like to hear from people who know (= stackoverflow users) if MVA would be useful, if it would be a total waste of time, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a Platinum MVA member myself I must say MVA is quite useful if you are pursuing FREE knowledge relating to Microsoft product. There are a lot of videos which are categorized on the basis of difficulty.
You need to first decide what you want to learn and then find its courses on and start following that. It acts as a stepping stone.
I also started my app dev by watching videos on MVA.
*There are two categories*
**Windows 8.1** and **Windows 10**
Would suggest you start first with `Bob Tabor` videos of App development(using code behind to get basic idea). Followed by `Jerry Nixon's` videos of windows 10(using MVVM).
You can find most of videos on `Channel9` MVA helps in better tracking your progress.
Now coming to second part **Proficiency**  
Currently with current videos you will be able to design Basic Apps easily using code behind features. But once you enter industry and with current windows 10 dev you will find developers switching over to MVVM and making code behind as little as possible. So yes as a stepping stone these videos are great and free. But for more advanced dev you will need to find more resources later on based on MVVM.

Comment: That's good to know. I didn't want to spend time doing something nobody thought was worthwhile. Thanks!

Comment: Also the courses are for your on knowledge. On resume they dont have any value but you lear quite a lot. Do check out know it prove it events of microsoft where they dare us to complete course of our choosing in a month all from MVA